# Completion of inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, complete-spaces

Let $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a real inner product space. Then, there exists a linear isometry from $X$ to its dual $X'$, whose image is dense.

I know that in the case $X$ is complete, the linear isometry we can use is $\Phi_X:X\to X'$ defined by $\Phi_X(x)=\langle\cdot,x\rangle$, and use the Fréchet-Riesz representation theorem.

Now, for general $X$, I want to define the same mapping. It is still a linear isometry, but not surjective anymore since surjectivity requires $X$ to be complete. Therefore, I want to show denseness of $\Phi_X(X)$ in $X'$. However, this is where I get stuck. I want to show that $\overline{\Phi_X(X)}=X'$. The first "$\subseteq$" follows easily, but how do i show "$\supseteq$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your title: work on the completion of $X$; as $X$ is dense in its completion, its image $\Phi_X(X)$ is dense in $X'$.

Comment: But what I want to show that $\Phi_X$ is a completion.

Comment: Yes, the closure of $\Phi_X(X)$ is $X'$. Not sure what else you expect.

Comment: Well, I have to show of course... and I have trouble showing that $X'\subseteq\overline{\Phi_X(X)}$

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see what else you want. You work on the completion of $X$, then as you mentioned  you get that $\overline{\phi_X(\overline X)}=X'$, but $\Phi_X$ is an isometry so $\phi_X(\overline X)=\overline{\phi_X(X)}$.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, I don't work on the completion, I work on an arbitrary inner product space $X$ and I define $\Phi_X:X\to X'$ as in Fréchet-Riesz representation theorem. I know this map is a  linear isometry, but in general it is not surjective. Therefore, I want to show that $\Phi_X(X)$ is dense in $X'$. I do not assume any completeness on $X$.

Comment: Neither do I.  Sorry, I don't follow. What prevents you from using the completion of $X $?

Comment: Allright, so let $(\tilde{X},\iota)$ denote a completion of $X$ with $\iota:X\to\tilde{X}$. Then, we can define $\Phi_{\tilde{X}}:\tilde{X}\to X'$. This is an isometric isomorphism by Fréchet Riesz-representation theorem. Can we now define $T:X\to X'$ by $T=\Phi_{\tilde{X}}\circ\iota$? We can clearly see that $T$ is a linear isometry. Now, we only need to show Denseness of the image of $T$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying all the time. You have $$\overline{T(X)}=\overline{\Phi_X(\iota(X))}=\Phi_X(\overline{\iota(X)})=\Phi_X(\overline X)=X'.$$